# OSError: [WinError 126] when importing a library in python

Tags: python, windows, api, dll, python-3.7

i am using the cubemos skeleton tracking Api (using for extract skeleton keypoints from pictures and videos).
i have a very weird problem:
everything was working fine, until one day, i received this error (also added image):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/omria/PycharmProjects/skeletonTracking/skeletonTracking.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cubemos.skeleton_tracking.nativewrapper import Api, SkeletonKeypoints
  File "C:\Users\omria\PycharmProjects\skeletonTracking\venv\lib\site-packages\cubemos\skeleton_tracking\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .nativewrapper import *
  File "C:\Users\omria\PycharmProjects\skeletonTracking\venv\lib\site-packages\cubemos\skeleton_tracking\nativewrapper.py", line 28, in <module>
    os.path.join(cubemos_dir, "bin", "cubemos_skeleton_tracking.dll")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X40k2.png)

and line 3 is when i'm importing the library: 
`from cubemos.skeleton_tracking.nativewrapper import Api`

another weird thing, is that the problem was fixed randomly without me doing anything, and then it returned again!
i tried reinstalling the cubemos SDK, rebooting the computer, debug, and i really don't know what is the source of this problem.
it seems like its some problem with my OS (i have windows 10, and using python 3.7 and VENV and PIP for the project)
i tried to figure out if the path is the problem, but again, it was working before, and i can't really tell if that is the problem. what do you think is causing this?
i will appreciate any help.
thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using a conda env. Demos worked but not the python sample. I explicitly added `%CUBEMOS_SKEL_SDK%\bin` to my Path environment since I had nothing before. That got it going. The `%CUBEMOS_SKEL_SDK%` was set up okay from the start.